# Servlet - Custom Classes must be thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

If i have a custom class, that have a static variable inside, i imagine that this static variable will be shared among all request threads, right? So I imagine that is my responsibility to control the access to variable to get the desired behavior.

In the example below, do static variable value will be shared among all request threads?
 Can i guarantee that result from `myCustom.getValue()` will be always be ZERO? I believe not.

> ```
> public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
>
>     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
>         CustomClass myCustom = new CustomClass();
>         myCustom.add();
>         myCustom.dec();
>         myCustom.getValue(); //
>     } 
> }
>
> public class CustomClass {
>   private static int value = 0;
>
>   public void add(){
>       this.value ++;
>   }
>
>   private void dec(){
>       this.value --;
>   }
>
>   private int getValue(){  
>       return this.value;
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. A `static` field belongs to the class, not to the instance. If any other thread (or your current one) is calling (or has called) `add` or `dec`, which operate on this `static` field, then you won't be able to guarantee getting back the initial value of `0`.